# How to access MailItems within the Email List pane?

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, ms-office

I'm working on an Outlook 2013 plugin that needs to access the emails currently displayed in the email list pane.

I already searched around a lot but I could only find ways to list emails within the current selected folder:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder curFolder = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
Outlook.Items mailItems = curFolder.Items;
MailItem item = mailItems.GetFirst();
```

This would work fine if the user didn't apply any search filters; but if a filter is applied via the instant search bar this code would produce the same list of MailItems as if the filter wasn't applied.

I thought of two ways of potentially solving this but couldn't find any resources online that worked for either.
1) Preferably, get direct read access to the MailItem list currently rendered within the email list pane.
2) Alternatively, read the value in the instant search text-box and apply that to the currently selected folder using the `Items.Find(`) command.

Any guidance or explanations would be greatly appreciated; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any direct access to the filter line or items shown in Outlook.

But the Explorer class provides the [CurrentView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861617(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an object representing the current view. The View class provides the [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868066(v=office.15).aspx) property which is applied to the current view.

```
Sub ResetView()  
   Dim v as Outlook.View  
   ' Save a reference to the current view object  
   Set v = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView  

   ' v.Filter
End Sub
```

So, you can apply the filter to the Items collection and get the same set of items.

Comment: Are you saying that the CurrentView.Filter property is equivalent to the combination of all of the filters set within the instant search bar? When I reference `Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.Filter` it returns stuff like this: `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/85700003" = 0`. The Filter method only accepts a string so how could I use this Filter property you mentioned?

Comment: You can use the Restrict or Find/FindNext methods of the Items class. See  [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/) and [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) for more information.

Comment: As stated earlier I'm aware-of and have used the Find & FindNext methods. In the first url you posted you used a string `[UnRead] = true` in your Find method call. Since the filter line is un-accessible is there some way to generate a string similar to your example using the Filter property you mentioned?

Comment: Did you try to use the Filter property value?

Comment: Yes, if I use the Filter property value I will get a run-time error `Condition is not valid`. I'm presuming this is because the string representation of the Filter property looks like `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/85‌​700003" = 0` and I would need it to be in a format like `[UnRead] = true`.

Comment: See [Filtering a Custom Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863459(v=office.15).aspx).